# Finding one-to-one correspondence between two infinite sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a surjective map of infinite sets. Let $C$ be a countable subset of $B$. Suppose that $f^{-1}(y)$ has two elements if $y\in C$, and one element if $y\in B-C$. Show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $B$.

So I thought to define a function $\phi:B\rightarrow A$. It's given that for $y\in B-C$, $f^{-1}(y)$ is one-to-one so we know for those elements we are fine. The only thing to do is find a correspondence for the elements in $C$. But since we know that there are two elements in $A$ corresponding to each of these elements in $C$. How can this possibly be one-to-one?

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to exploit the countability of $C$.  So there is an element $1$ of $C$, element $2$ of $C$, etc.  Rewrite $f$ as follows: Leave $f$ on $B \setminus C$ alone.  For each pair of elements of $A$ each mapped to the same element of $C$, arbitrarily designate one of them as 'odd' and the other as 'even'.  Then remap them by parity --- i.e., change the mapping from the $i$th pair in $A$ to the $i$th element of $C$, to map the 'odd' element to the $(2*i-1)$th element of $C$ and the 'even' element to the $(2*i)$th element of C.

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}[C]$ is also countable as a $2$-$1$ preimage of a countable set.

So $A$ is the union of a countable set $f^{-1}[C]$ and a set in $A \setminus f^{-1}[C] \simeq B\setminus C$ (by $f$ restricted). As any two countably infinite sets are equinumerous, $B \simeq A$ is then obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Axiom of Choice to form the set $A_1$ made up of exactly one element of each set $f^{-1}(y)$ and let $A_2 = A \backslash A_1$.  Then apply cardinal arithmetic. Note that $f|_{A_1}:A_1 \rightarrow B$ and $f|_{A_2}: A_2 \rightarrow B$ are one-to-one, so we have $|A_1|, |A_2| \leq B$. Thus $$|A| = |A_1| + |A_2| \leq |B| + |B| = 2|B| = |B|$$ (since $2|B| = |B|$ for any infinite set $B$). We already know $|A| \geq |B|$ since $f$ is surjective, so $|A| = |B|$ by Shroeder-Bernstein. Note that we did not need countability of $C$.